# CasperJSでエラー発生時に処理を継続させたい

Tags: javascript, casperjs

以下のコードで、存在しない要素`#hoge`を取得しようとしたとき、エラーで処理がストップし、後続の`#economy`の処理を実行できません。
エラーが発生しても処理を継続させる方法はないでしょうか？

```
var casper = require('casper').create();    
casper.start('http://www.yahoo.co.jp');

casper.then(function(){
  this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#topics').html);  //#topicsは存在する
  this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#hoge').html);  //#hogeは存在しない
  this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#economy').html);  //#economyは存在する
});

casper.run(function(){
  this.exit;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まっとうにやるなら [casper.exists](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#exists) ですかね？

```
diff --git a/test.js b/test.js
index e4c0fb2..9d75a06 100644
--- a/test.js
+++ b/test.js
@@ -3,7 +3,9 @@ casper.start('http://www.yahoo.co.jp');

 casper.then(function(){
   this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#topics').html);  //#topicsは存在する
-  this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#hoge').html);  //#hogeは存在しない
+  if (this.exists('#hoge')) {
+    this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#hoge').html);  //#hogeは存在しない
+  }
   this.echo(this.getElementInfo('#economy').html);  //#economyは存在する
 });
```

Comment: 取得する前に、存在するかどうか確認すれば良かったんですね。
ありがとうございました。